# How to get the WiFI Security Key/Connected WiFi Device using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, child-process

Using the command line `netsh wlan show interfaces` shows the output below, however I'm trying to make a script where it can pull `Profile                : 3MobileWiFi-3D71` and only return the result after the `:` so then I can make a JS Script to then use this data with the following command line `Netsh wlan show profile name="${DeviceFromInterfaces}" key=clear` which then will only return the following data I need: `Key Content            : REDACTED`

How would I get this data using this module:
`child_process` which uses `exec` to run most of the stuff aforementioned.

```
Security settings
-----------------
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : GCMP
    Security key           : Present
    Key Content            : REDACTED
```

[Interfaces]

```
There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : WiFi
    Description            : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
    GUID                   : REDACTED
    Physical address       : REDACTED
    State                  : connected
    SSID                   : 3MobileWiFi-3D71
    BSSID                  : REDACTED
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Connection mode        : Profile
    Channel                : 11
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 65
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 65
    Signal                 : 90%
    Profile                : 3MobileWiFi-3D71

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use `child_process.spawn` or `child_process.spawnSync` to run the commands, and then use regular expressions to parse the output. Here's what that would look like for the first command:

```js
import {spawn} from 'child_process';

let stdOut = '';

const evaluator = spawn('netsh', ['wlan', 'show', 'interfaces']);

evaluator.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  stdOut += data.toString();
});

evaluator.on('close', () => {
  const regex = /^profile.*:\s/i;
  const profile = stdOut
    .split('\n')
    .map((ln) => ln.trim())
    .find((ln) => ln.match(regex))
    .replace(regex, '');
  console.log(profile);
});
```

The callback provided to the `close` event on `evaluator` would return the profile name, after which you could take that output and pipe it into your next command — using the same type of logic to parse out the necessary data.